# SAS: Write a macro...

Tags: macros, sas

I am having a question on SAS Macro (I do analytics in R and python, No SAS). SO, it is getting me into some lack of understanding in syntax of SAS in solving the following question.

Write a macro that accepts a table name, a column name, a list of integers, a main axis label and an x axis label. This function should scan over each element in the list of integers and produce a histogram for each integer value, setting the bin count to the element in the input list, and labeling main and x-axis with the specified parameters. You should label the y-axis to read Frequency, bins = and the number of bins.

Also I need to test macro with a data set, using bin numbers 12, 36, and 60. So, that I am able to call macro with something like

```
%plot_histograms(data, y, 12 36 60, main="Title", xlabel="x_label");
to plot three different histograms of the data set.
```

Hint: Assume 12 36 60 resolve to a single macro parameter and use %scan, macro definition can look something like

```
%macro plot_histograms(table_name, column_name, number_of_bins, main="Main", xlabel="X Label")
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please explain what a 'bin' is?

Comment: The bins in a histogram correspond to the bars.  They're called bins because you imagine someone sorting [items] into bins based on whatever attribute you're doing the histogram on.

Comment: No. of bins in histograms. it takes them automatically to the size of the a list of integers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question and this is not a free code platform anyway but this should point you in the right direction

```
%macro plot_histograms(table_name, column_name, number_of_bins, main="Main", xlabel="X Label");
    %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&number_of_bins.); /* loop accross elements in your input list */
      proc gchart data=&table_name.; /*make a chart for the provided table */
          ...
          /* whatever it is you actually need to do, fetch the current element of the input list like this */
          %scan(&number_of_bins.,&i.)
          ...
      run;
    %end;
%mend;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you really should try this on your own and let us know where you get stuck.

That said, let's break down how to solve this problem.

Make some test data;

```
data test;
do i=1 to 10000;
    r = rannor(1);
    output;
end;
run;
```

How do I create a histogram with this?  Use `PROC SGPLOT`

```
proc sgplot data=test;
histogram r / nbins=10;
xaxis label="X LABEL";
yaxis label="Y LABEL";
run;
```

Produces this:
[image]

So, if I make a macro to create this generally:

```
%macro histogram(data,column,bin,xlabel,ylabel);
    proc sgplot data=&data;
    histogram &column / nbins=&bin;
    xaxis label="&xlabel";
    yaxis label="&ylabel";
    run;
%mend;
```

Now `%histogram(test,r,10,X LABEL,Y LABEL)'` produces the same image.

Let's write something that loops over the values of bins and call this macro:

```
%macro make_histograms(data,column,bins,xlabel,ylabel);
   %local i n bin;
   %let n=%sysfunc(countw(&bins)); /*Number of words in &bins*/
   %do i=1 %to &n;
      %let bin=%scan(&bins,&i);  /*Get the nth bin*/
      %histogram(&data,&column,&bin,&xlabel,&ylabel);
   %end;
%mend;
```